# Given a string, remove a the repeating consecutive characters using c++

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    int n= s.length();
    string ans;
    ans[0]=s[0];
    int j=1;
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        if(s[i]!=s[i-1]){
            ans[j]=s[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    ans[n]='\0';
    cout<<ans<<endl;
    // for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    //  cout<<ans[i];
    // }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to print the variable `ans` using simple `cout<<ans<<endl`. Instead I have to use a loop to print it. Why is that?

Comment: "I am not able to print the variable 'ans' " what does that mean?

Comment: `string ans;` directly followed by `ans[0]=s[0];` leads to *undefined behavior*. The string `ans` is *empty* and any and all indexing into it will be out of bounds. That is probably the cause for your problem as you continue to do that. Use e.g. `ans += s[0]` to append characters.

Comment: As for your problem, unless it's for a school assignment or similar use [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: Yeah appending the characters in the string worked.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
string ans;
```

`ans` is a string of lenght `0`. Already in the next line you invoke undefined behavior by trying to modify an element beyond the end of the string:

```
ans[0]=s[0];
```

You can add characters to a string via `ans += character;` or `ans.push_back(character);`. You cannot print `ans` via `std::cout` because you never add a character to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about C++ but in C strings are character array. So let's say you define a string like this:

```
char ans[]="Hello";
```

It'll store the string in form of an array of characters while ans will be pointing to the first element of array.

The thing is array designators(the names you use for an array) are implicitly converted into pointer. So for string `ans`, it is not a whole container which stores the whole string `Hello` but instead it will be pointing to first block of group of sequentially arranged containers those hold `H` `e` `l` `l` `o` characters individually.

So if you print `ans` so it'll only give the data of the container it's pointing to instead of whole group of containers.

Although the answer is not that relevant I hope the concept helps.

Comment: *"So if you print `ans` so it'll only give the data of the container it's pointing to instead of whole group of containers."* - is a very confusing statement and most likely wrong as well. `operator<<` of `std::ostream` has an overload for printing out null-terminated byte strings (passed in as `const char*`)